# Bayes Net classifier for a large set

Tags: machine-learning, weka, classification

So here's another difficult question. I'm looking for the equivalent of Weka's Bayes Net classifier. Notice that it is different from Naive Bayes. Problem with Weka is that it uses too much memory and so cannot handle large data sets.

Needs to handle a few million examples set, work on Windows.

Comment: So, what are you looking for then? An algorithm? An implementation in....what language?

Comment: @user1123466 were you using [Weka's library](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/) or their executable application?

Answer (score 1):

To (partially) answer my own question, Knime has an extansion for using Weka components. It seems to handle memory better by an order of magnitude.

Still, I'm looking for another app, command line utility or maybe a Python library.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit `RunWeka.ini` where weka is installed.
Open `RunWeka.ini` and change `maxheap=128m` to `maxheap=1024m`, then `save.finish`.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on Windows, there is another option. Microsoft has this bayesian networks toolkit called [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/). But it is not open-sourced.